# What wire gauge for my LED lit sculpture?

Tags: led

Thank you all for the prior advise on what LED to use with my sculpt!! [Here is a pic](https://imgur.com/a/3ePBHQ5)I ended up using this [LED](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CUGACUO) I hung the sculpt and lit it with this magnet [Wire](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NYCCVR7) and now I want to enlarge the thickness of it (looks too thin). Can I safely use something like 16 gauge wire with this LED (with 2 aaa batteries)? Also Is the Magnet wire safe to use if lit all day? Thanks for the help on my first LED project!

Comment: The question is a mess but I don't know how to fix it without removing basically everything. This is not a forum and there are no "you all" - no one knows or is supposed to know about your previous question, each question must stand alone to make it helpful to other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnet wire is safe. Just not durable. 16AWG is appreciably overkill but will certainly work technically and safely.